# Python reflection: How to get the id of a specific instance of a method from inside itself?

Tags: python, oop, methods, dynamic, reflection

I can't just use something straightforward like `id(self.methodname)` because the scenario is a little more complicated than that since I'm doing funky dynamic stuff. I'll try to explain the whole situation clearly.

```py
class A:
     def __init__(self):
         self.ax = 10
     def amethod(self, other):
         print(self.ax)
         print(other.bx)

class B:
     def __init__(self):
         self.fun_dict = {}
         self.bx = 20
     def run_in_dict(self):
         for fn in self.fun_dict.values():
             fn()
```

First we have two classes. One of them has a dictionary that will contain functions as values and those function's ids as keys. In the actual program this is for storing callback functions, and `fun_dict` is instead named something like `on_receiving`.

```py
a = A()
b = B()
import types
bound_to_b = types.MethodType(a.amethod, b)
print(bound_to_b)  # <bound method A.amethod of <__main__.B object at 0x7fdcdacf1850>>
print(bound_to_b())  # prints 10 and 20
b.fun_dict[id(bound_to_b)] = bound_to_b
b.run_in_dict() # also prints 10 and 20
a.ax = 2
b.run_in_dict() # prints 2 and 20, as expected
```

So far so good. All of this is working as intended: we now have a method bound_to_b that's bound to *two* objects simultaneously, and it's been stored in b's `fun_dict`. Yes, I know this is kind of horrible code but it's a learning project so don't worry, nobody will be exposed to it.

But now let's say I later want to remove the bound method from b. That is, remove its reference from `b.fun_dict`. This is easy enough if I'm doing it from outside and have the id saved somewhere else, but my question is: Is there a way to do it from inside `amethod` without storing the id? Or if it's not possible, is there something other than the id that can be used as a dict key that would make it possible?

`print(id(self.amethod))` in fact prints a different memory position every time, so it doesn't help. Nothing else inside `dir(bound_to_b)` jumps out at me either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you can't get a reference to a method in the method generically the way I want, at least not without a lot of mucking about with even more hacky things like `inspect`. Anyway it's probably quite a silly idea to try to store data in a function, which I assume it's why it's so hard to do.
Instead I made a thin wrapper class for callback functions. This does what I want, although it does require passing in an extra argument to the method:

```py
import types
class Callback:
    def __init__(self, f):
        self.f = f
    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs["cbid"] = id(self)
        self.f(*args, **kwargs)


class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.ax = 10
    def amethod(self, other, cbid=None):
        print("from inside amethod")
        other.fun_dict.pop(cbid)

class B:
    def __init__(self):
        self.fun_dict = {}
        self.bx = 20
    def run_in_dict(self):
        for fn in list(self.fun_dict.values()):
            print("before:", self.fun_dict)
            fn()
            print("after:", self.fun_dict)

a = A()
b = B()
bound = Callback(types.MethodType(a.amethod, b))
b.fun_dict[id(bound)] = bound
b.run_in_dict()
```